# VB.net click site button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have been trying to 'click' a button on a site , but I can't get it working.

This is the button I'm talking about:

```
<div data-expected-currency="1" data-asset-type="T-Shirt" class="PurchaseButton btn-medium btn-primary" data-se="item-buyforfree" data-item-name="Yoshi tux" data-item-id="1788861" data-expected-price="0" data-product-id="231582" data-expected-seller-id="78049" data-bc-requirement="0" data-seller-name="robosapien626">
                                     Take One
                                </div>
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If elem.InnerText.Trim = "PurchaseButton btn-medium btn-primary" Then
            elem.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

It does not do anything.
Other buttons with an actual ID do work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GetAttribute` after the tag name so you can find the button and click it:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If element.GetAttribute("class") = "PurchaseButton btn-medium btn-primary" Then 
            element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.InnerText` of that element is `Take One` with some whitespace around it, so you can try

```
If elem.InnerText.Trim = "Take One" Then
```

or

```
If elem.OuterHtml.Contains("PurchaseButton btn-medium btn-primary") Then
```